# how to detect if the cancel button is pressed during the facebook login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login

i have implemented the Facebook login and it's work correctly. But i have a trouble with this screen:

[image]

this is provided directly by Facebook framework, so i can't directly attach an action on it.
that view is use to associate my Facebook app to my Facebook account. So the question is:
how can i detect if the user press cancel button?
i have tried to print the state of my Facebook session

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"stato %u",state);
    
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateCreated:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateCreatedOpening:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            // Once the user has logged in, we want them to
            // be looking at the root view.
            
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

but it return always the same state, independently by the button pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by adding this line of code to the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; ;
}
```

and by checking the state of the connection with:

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What state is always returned? This suggests there is something else not setup correctly?

You should be able to add something like this to your viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear.

```
// See if the app has a valid token for the current state.
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
    // To-do, show logged in view
} else {
    // No, display the login page.
    [self showLoginView];
}
```

Comment: the method 'FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded' always return NO! even if i click in the ok button or in the cancel button! the result is always no!

Comment: when i print the state i get this number : 257, that matching with FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed inside the switch, but FBSessionState Open is never call.

Comment: If you are always getting FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed then there must be another issue. How are you opening the state? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/